# Custom ngSwitch style directive

Tags: angular

I am trying to introduce experimental components into my application. This means that I have component A used in a parent template and I want to replace A with a new experimental component B based on some config that enables the experiment per user.

```html
<div *experimentalDesign="experiment-id">
  <app-comp-a *experimentEnabled></app-comp-a>
  <app-comp-b *experimentDisabled></app-comp-b>
</div>
```

This would be almost identical with the ngSwitch directive use case, except that here I can control having only 2 options + it is custom to my use case and I can resolve the experiment config in the directive.

I researched implementing a structural directive for **experimentalDesign** though I am not sure how to connect it to the child components and their **experimentEnabled** and **experimentDisabled** directives.

How would I go about implementing something like this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you look at the `ngSwitch` and `ngSwitchCase` code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/directives/ng_switch.ts) it's fairly straightforward - on your "child" directives you look for a "parent" directive on the host to get it's reference and then you work with that to resolve whether the template should be rendered or not.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I forgot that the angular code is open sourced! Will follow this!